# Storing downloaded files in memory

Tags: python, multiprocessing, urllib2

I'm trying to download multiple image files from two websites, and am doing it using multiprocessing module, hoping to shorten the time needed (synchronously it would be about five minutes). This is the code being executed in a separate process:

```
def _get_image(self):
        if not os.path.isdir(self.file_path + self.folder):
            os.makedirs(self.file_path + self.folder)

        rand = Random()
        rand_num = rand.randint(0, sys.maxint)
        self.url += str(rand_num)
        opener = urllib.FancyURLopener()
        opener.retrieve(self.url, self.file_path + self.folder + '/' + str(rand_num) + '.jpg')
```

The above code is executed in separate processes and works ok, though I'd like it not to save each file right after it's downloaded, but at the end of the process execution. After download, I'd like them to be stored in some internal list, or dict... Sadly, FancyURLopener doesn't allow to store files in memory, and insists on writing them to the disk right after download. Is there a tool like FancyURLopener, but without the disk-writes?

Comment: Consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`URLopener.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.URLopener.open) returns a file-like. You can `read()` it to retreive the data as a byte string, then store it wherever you want.

Why do you need a `URLopener` in the first place? How about a simple [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)?

Comment: I used FancyURLopener because of it's 'fancy' part - handling 404, and so on, but for now your answer will do. Maybe later I'll subclass FancyURLopener and rewrite it's retrieve method so that it will store the byte strings in memory rather than saving them to the disk. Thanks!